# Duda programación concurrente en java

Tags: java, hilos

he editado esta pregunta por si acaso no se entienda bien.

Estoy haciendo un programa en java con hilos, se trata de un programa donde 10 robots (hilos) usan de forma concurrente un recurso (100 piezas) pero para usar una pieza necesita tener un destornillador y un equilibrador, de los cuales solo se dispone 3 de cada uno. Cuando un robot tiene un destornillador y un equilibrador puede usar una pieza y seguidamente suelta el destornillador y el equilibrador.

Creo que el programa funciona correctamente, pero si alguien puede confirmarmelo estaría muy agradecido.

Dejo el enlace con la carpeta de las clases: [Enlace](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xyBrLqHeiSzcH87X6wKjQurlMPiqvcZi)

> ·Main

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        CentroDeMontaje montaje = new CentroDeMontaje();
        
        for(int d=0;d<=3;d++)
            for(int e=0;e<=3;e++)
                for(int i=1;i<11;i++) {
                    Robots robots = new Robots(montaje, i, d, e);
                    robots.start();
                }
        montaje.robotsEnAccion();
    }
}
```

> ·CentroDeMontaje

```
public class CentroDeMontaje {

    int piezas = 100;
    int numPiezasConsumidas = 0;
     
    public synchronized void robotsConstructores(int numRobot, int idDestornillador, int idEquilibrador) {
        while (piezas == 0) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(idDestornillador==0) {
            System.out.println("El robot "+numRobot+" está esperando para coger un destornillador.");
        }else {
            System.out.println("El robot "+numRobot+" ha cogido el destornillador "+idDestornillador);
        }
        if(idEquilibrador==0) {
            System.out.println("El robot "+numRobot+" está esperando para coger un equilibrador.");
        }else {
            System.out.println("El robot "+numRobot+" ha cogido el equilibrador "+idEquilibrador);
        }

        if(idDestornillador>0 && idEquilibrador>0) {
            piezas--;
            numPiezasConsumidas++;
            System.out.println("El robot "+numRobot+" terminó con la pieza "+numPiezasConsumidas+" y suelta el destornillador "+idDestornillador);
            System.out.println("El robot "+numRobot+" terminó con la pieza "+numPiezasConsumidas+" y suelta el equilibrador "+idEquilibrador);
        }
    }

    public synchronized void robotsEnEspera() {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void robotsEnAccion() {
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

> ·robots

```
public class Robots extends Thread{
    CentroDeMontaje montaje;
    int numRobot;
    int idDestornillador;
    int idEquilibrador;
    
    public Robots(CentroDeMontaje montaje, int numRobot, int destornilladores, int equilibradores){
        this.montaje=montaje;
        this.numRobot=numRobot;
        this.idDestornillador=destornilladores;
        this.idEquilibrador=equilibradores;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=1;i<11;i++) {
            montaje.robotsConstructores(numRobot, idDestornillador, idEquilibrador);
            yield();
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Ah vale, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya he conseguido resolver el fallo que tenia el programa, por si a alguien le interesa dejo aquí la solución y más abajo el enlace. Un saludo.

En la clase main hay que modificar estos bucles for, de forma que en vez de aumentar de 0 a 3, disminuya de 3 a 0, básicamente al revés de como lo tenía anteriormente.

```java
        for(int d=3;d>=3;d--)
            for(int e=3;e>=3;e--)
```

Espero que a alguien le sirva, ya que al fin y al cabo es un ejercicio de programación en java con hilos.

[Enlace del proyecto](https://drive.google.com/open?id=14cCC_LEbloT_5WmzDW5PQXP8wmbE_qw3)